# String Extraction on the basis of index location in sql server

Tags: sql-server

Can we get characters from a string based on there index position.

Example : There is a string 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQR'

I want to extract all characters which are at even position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @Aishvarya and @Arvo suggestion, code would be like below. Pretty simple.

```
declare @input varchar(100) = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQR'
declare @output varchar(100) = ''

declare @index int = 1
declare @max_index int = (select len(@input))

while @index <= @max_index
begin
    if @index % 2 = 0
        set @output = @output + substring(@input, @index, 1)

    set @index = @index + 1
end

print @output -- BDFHJLNPR
```

Comment: Note you make a loop iterate even less times by adding incrementing `@index` by 2 *after* 1st iteration (`@index` = 1) is over.

Answer (score 1):

Index starts with 1 in SQL so use `Substring`

```
 SELECT SUBSTRING('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQR', 1, 1) //returns the character at 2nd position
 SELECT SUBSTRING('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQR', 3, 1) //returns the character at 4th position
```

and so on.

Comment: sorry Aishvarya you not got my question. I want all the character to be return in query which are located at even position.

Comment: You want the characters in even position don't you?

Comment: @KunalChoudhary - explain better then, Aishvarya's answer looks correct to me either.

Comment: want result as BDFHJLNPR

Comment: @KunalChoudhary - and what prohibits you just adding these substrings or make little loop for longer strings? There is no internal function for your need.

Comment: @AishvaryaKarthik I suggest changing that 3 in second query to 4 according to your code comment.